# Hidden Markov Model EM Training: Linking states to hidden variables

Tags: hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization, baum-welch

I want to implement the Baum Welch Algorithm for unsupervised training of Hidden Markov Models, I am however still a little unclear on some details, especially this one:

Before learning the optimal probabilities $\lambda$ (initial, transition and emission) the structure of the HMM is fixed. For that it needs to know how many hidden variables there are and then builds $|H|^n + 2$ states, where $H$ is the set of hidden variables, $n$ is the order of the model and 2 for one initial and one final state. Then it connects all states with each other with random probabilities such that $\sum_j a_{ij} = 1$ where $i, j \in H$ and $a_{ij}$ is the transition probability. Furthermore it needs to know the number of observed variables $O$. Then it connects all states built from $H$ with states for all variables of $O$, again such that $\sum_j b_i(o_j) = 1$ where $i \in H$ and $o_j \in O$ and $b_i(o_j)$ denotes the emission probability of observed variable $o$ from state $i$.

When training is successful the parameters $\lambda$ should be such that the state machine is more or less isomorphic (under consideration of the transition, emission and initial probabilities, as the structure is isomorphic as a precondition) to a model that would have been trained on the same data but in a supervised training (assuming we possess the data in annotated form). But the model has no information about the semantics of the hidden variables, so then while the model might be isomorphic, how does one actually establish the connection between the hidden variable set outside of the model and the states inside the state machine of the HMM?

Meaning, say the model has trained itself to assign to some observation $o$ the state sequence $q_1, q_2, q_3$ as the most likely one. How do I know which of my outside hidden variables from my set $H$ corresponds to either state?

Comment: Closely similar: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/72357/755, http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/21519/10726, http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/18057/8560.